# Why do we use lambda when binding function to QAction

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt, pyqt5

I know `lambda` is use when calling anonymous functions like:

```
double = lambda x: x * 2
```

However, I don't quite understand why do I have to use `lambda` when binding a function to a `QAction` object in the following scenario:

```
class UiMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainwindows):

        mainwindows.setObjectName("MainWindow")
       
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainwindows)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 484, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")

        mainwindows.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(mainwindows)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(lambda:self.test())

        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(mainwindows)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainwindows)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open..."))


    def test(self):
        win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
```

Comment: What makes you think that you have to use a `lambda`?

Comment: Without lambda the function fires automatically as soon as the code runs, without even clicking the binded item.

Comment: Well, what happens in the following two lines of your code? Aren't they also trying to link an event from QT to some of your methods?

Comment: No. I know how to make things work but what i mean is that i don't understand why do i have to use lambda to make things work in this situation as the function is explicitly defined and lambda documentations says it is for anonymous functions.